# Is it mandatory to upload screenshots for all screensizes when submitting to the app Store?

Tags: app-store-connect

I am preparing a new application, and iOS requires screenshots of the application. They ask for screenshots in the following sizes:

[image]

Is it necessary to upload screenshots for all resolutions?

What will be the ramifications if I only upload screenshots for 5.5-Inch and iPad?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand if you *only* upload 5.5inch and iPad, they'll just reject you outright. Currently, it looks like they require at least 4 and 3.5. If you indicate it's optimized for iPhone 6, it also requires a 4.7.

It looks like if it indicates that it runs on iPad you need both an iPad an iPad Pro.

Check out the requirements for yourself here: [iTunes Connect Dev Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW2)

Remember, required/requirements means it's **mandatory**.

Answer (score 0):

Now you only need to upload a 5.5-inch screenshot

Comment: This is an answer, @Peter  . It says you only have to upload one size. It might be a right answer or a wrong answer - people should vote and comment and possibly edit to explain or source the answer with documentation.